# Skipping nodes when using DomXpath in PHP

Tags: php, html, domxpath

I'm using a DomXpath query to find all HTML elements in a file that contain text that a user would see when the page is rendered by the browser.

The following lines of code do the trick pretty well:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$results = $xpath->query("//text()");
```

However, there are some side effects. For example, if you have a

```
<style>
```

tag in your HTML it will read inside it and parse all CSS elements and I'd like to totally ignore it. I can't seem to find a way to form the query above to ignore one or more text element. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to avoid the `<style>` tag.

```
$results = $xpath->query("//body//text()")
```

This will ignore anything before the body of the HTML file.